# Differences between "stay away from, keep away from, far from"

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-difference

When referring to "to not go near a particular person or place", can "stay away from" and "keep away from" be interchangeable?
e.g.
I want you to stay away from my daughter.
I want you to keep away from my daughter.

While "far away" means a long distance away, mainly used to talking about two places that are not near each other. Am I right?

"Stay away from" and "keep away from" describes an action of "not going near " while "far away" describes a state.

Am I right?

Comment: "**stay** away from" and "**keep** away from" contain *verbs* (stay, keep), while "far away" contains no verbs. You can add a a verb to it: "**stay** far away from my daughter".

Comment: @CopperKettle Do you mean the three phrases"stay away from", "keep away from" and "stay far away from" can be interchangeable?

Comment: From the grammar standpoint, they are all okay. Their general meaning is similar, but I'm not a native speaker of English to judge about shades of meaning. There might be some differences.

Answer (score 2):

In general you are correct that **stay away** and **keep away** can be used interchangeably without loss of **understanding**, meaning **don't go near**.  **Stay away** seems more AmE while **keep away** seems more BrE.

One way of thinking about the **distances** is to see usage of the **keywords** in other related phrases. As an native AmE speaker, my thinking behind my sense of the differences in distances involved is

***far from*** is the **most distance**, as it is **indeterminate**

> **far from** us, another civilisation may exist
>   **keep far away** is further away than **keep away**

***keep*** **away** is the **closest**, **keep** also has the meaning of **possession** which can imply things being **at-hand** or **within reach**

> **keep** clear of the moving train
>   **keep** to yourself

***stay*** **away** is somewhere in-between and possibly inclusive of **far away**'s distance

> He pointed and said "**stay** over there".

One would never say **keep over there**, thereby giving **stay** a farther meaning.

**Stay far away** and **keep far away** are interchangeable for me since the distances inherit the magnitude of **far**

For **stay away, keep away**, and **far away** the quantities involved are not as easily defined as the other descriptive adjectives **a few**, **some**, or **several**